# Classic ASP adding records to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, vbscript, asp-classic

I have had to move on of my old classic ASP projects to a new host, and I'm having problems connecting to their MySQL server.

I have attached below the script I used with the old host which now errors

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

After a bit of digging it seems I have to change the driver to `{MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}` but it still errors. It seems to point to the cursor/lock type but I have used all option with no success.

> ODBC driver does not support the requested properties.

```vb
<%
Dim Conn
Dim Rs
Dim sql

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=xxx; PORT=xxx; DATABASE=xxx; UID=xxx; PASSWORD=xxx; OPTION=3"

sql= "SELECT * FROM table;" 

Rs.CursorType = 2 
Rs.LockType = 3 

Rs.Open sql, Conn    

Rs.AddNew 

Rs.Fields("database") = Request.Form("form")

Rs.Update   
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Why are you using `AddNew()`? Just execute a SQL `INSERT` statement, its simpler and less error prone.

Comment: What was the original connection string *(minus any real server, user info)* that caused the `Data source name not found and no default driver specified` before you changed it?

Comment: @Lankymart well, for one, it's a simple way to protect against SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard while I agree I doubt very much that is why this method was used. Plus having to run a `SELECT` then have the ADODB `.Update()` to do the `INSERT` which is  two db calls instead of one maybe *simple* but inefficient.

Comment: @Lankymart true, and yes, classic ASP wasn't really designed to  be efficient, just simple to write and use. (That code is part of the basic classic ASP "features", I remember it from books and tutorials. :))

Comment: As far as I know the MySQL ODBC driver doesn't support the cursor/lock types which go with editable recordsets.  Did the environment on your old server use JET or SQL Server with an OLEDB driver?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need this to insert a record. Instead, use plain SQL which should be supported by all database drivers:

```
Dim oCommand
Const adInteger = 3
Const adDate = 7
Const adVarChar = 200
sql = "Insert Into table (database) Values (?)" 
Set oCommand = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCommand.ActiveConnection = Conn
oCommand.CommandText = sql
oCommand.Parameters.Append(oCommand.CreateParameter("database", adVarChar, , 512, Request.Form("form")) )
oCommand.Execute
```

This is indeed bit more to  write, but should preserve all the benefits of the other way (e.g. SQL Injections attack protection) and not being dependant on specific drivers.