# SQL statement to insert into database table not working - "Invalid column name"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, forms, asp-classic

I am creating a website with classic ASP on the backend. The form on the frontend submits to the Classic ASP page on the backend just fine. I am also able to connect to the database just fine. (I have tested both of these.)

The problem occurs when I try and add the form inputs into the database table. (form method is POST).

Here is what I am trying to do -

```
conn.Execute "insert into table1(firstn, lastn, dato, scene) values (fn, ln, sd, sce)"
```

table1 exists with firstn, lastn, dato, and scene as its columns. conn and the fn, sd, ln, sd, and sce variables have been declared and initialized correctly.

However, I am still getting an "Invalid column name fn" error. Why is that?

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Each string value must be surrounded with single quote - or better yet, use a prepared statement. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: `fn` refers to a column with the way you've expressed it here. Do you mean the variable `fn`?

Comment: Do this with prepared statements and placeholder values, then bind the data when executing.

Comment: @GMB they are string variables. Do I still need to do "... VALUES('fn', 'ln', ...)"?

Comment: @tadman YES, the variable fn. not a column. i want to insert a new set of results in the table.

Comment: Use [placeholder values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538979/how-can-i-make-a-prepared-statement-in-classic-asp-that-prevents-sql-injection) to specify where the data goes. These look like `?` or perhaps even `?fn`.

Comment: As another tip, try and use variable names that match the column names. There's no reason to refer to it as both `fn` and `firstn`. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Either concatenate the variables or if SQL injection is a concern, use parameters, which may be what GMB means by 'prepared statement'. I've never had concern about SQL injection in my local db so haven't used. I just concatenate. But since this is a web app, recommend parameterization.

Comment: You won't be able to add your form values like that, instead use an [`ADODB.Command` object to execute a parameterised query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014534/692942).

Comment: @June7 *"if SQL injection **is a concern**, use parameters"*?? There's no "if" just don't do it. There is no scenario where suggesting there is an alternative is viable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
conn.Execute "insert into table1(firstn, lastn, dato, scene) values (" &fn& ", " &ln& ", " &sd& ", " &sce& ")"
```

So you will input `fn`, `ln`, `sd` and `sce` as variables and not content into your query.

Comment: firstn, lastn are most likely strings i.e. your example will give an error as strings should be enclosed with a single quote '

Comment: No user2316116, he do not specified the type of the variable or column.

Comment: it doesn't mean it makes your answer correct. 1) you suggested a way to make the code vulnerable for sql injections 2) it will not work for values other than numeric values

Comment: The question is not about how to prevent slq injections and about why isn’t working